# How does MySQL handle overflow of decimal fields?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql 5.6 database with a field with the following definition:

`security_qty decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,`

This worked just fine for a long time but, suddenly an insert was attempted with a value that's bigger than 8 integer digits.

I could easily fix this changing the column definition but the problem I'm experiencing is that when this happens in production I get this error:

`An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'security_qty' at row 1`

But when I run it locally, on a Docker instance, I don't get any error, but the contents of the field for the offending row are `99999999.99` which is really annoying to say the least.

Looking around I found that there some small differences in the local and remote MySQL configuration. I got them matching and re-created the local db but the behaviour is still the same.

So I'm wondering if there's a particular MySQL setting that would define which of these options to use to handle the overflow which I'm not aware of.

Thanks,

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/out-of-range-and-overflow.html

Comment: Compare `SELECT @@sql_mode;`

Comment: Thanks @Akina. I just did that and found that there's a STRICT_TRANS_TABLES present in prod but not in docker... I think that's where the problem is.

Comment: Yes, and the link provided by @P.Salmon describes this.

Comment: Confirmed, I changed that and now they're both working identically. Thanks!!